# Deserializing JSON into C# object with Shopify API

Tags: c#, shopify

I want to convert the JSON output of the Shopify API call into an object I can manipulate in C#.

This is the code I have so far

```
1 var client = new ShopifyAPIClient(new ShopifyAuthorizationState { AccessToken = token, ShopName = shopName });
2 var orders = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject((string)client.Get("/admin/orders.json"));
3 
4 foreach(object order in orderss){
5  // do stuff with member variables of object
6 }
```

Error on line 4: *Type 'object' is not enumerable*

[this](http://api.shopify.com/order.html#index) page has the format of the JSON object returned.

[this](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/index.html?topic=html/SerializingJSON.htm) page has an example of how to deserialize JSON into a C# object that **has** a class defined

Is there any way to deserialize the JSON into a C# object that can be enumerable without defining a class? If not, are the Shopify classes defined somewhere where I can copy them into my project?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it has another `orders` object under root object. Try

```
dynamic dynObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
foreach (var order in dynObj.orders)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}  {1}", 
                        (string)order.email, 
                        (string)order.payment_details.credit_card_number);
}
```